# Getting issue while doing validation using jQuery with JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation

I have one text box in View in MVC and I have to validate this text box client side before submit.I'm using jquery for validation as following:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
            //validation at client side
            //------------------Code 1-------------------
            if ($("#txtName").val() == "") {
                alert("Please enter Name.");
                return false;
            }
            //------------------Code 1-------------------
            //------------------Code 2-------------------
            //call to database for validation
            $.getJSON("/Producy/IsExist?productname=toy", function (data) {
                if (data.IsExists == "1") {
                    alert("Product already exist.");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //------------------Code 2-------------------

        });
```

Validation working properly only with **Code 1** not with **Code 2**
When I click on submit message display "Product already exist" but form get posted even I wrote `return false` after alert message.Why it's doing such type of behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: do  $.getJSON( instead of $getJSON( . Missing a dot there.

Comment: ok i correct that one

Comment: what output for this -> data.IsExists?true or 1